# Flutter, Android - Is it possible to change status bar color on splash (launch) screen?

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, android-statusbar

I'm trying to change status bar color on the Splash Screen in Flutter for Android. But, whatever I do, it's color remaining unchanged (black). I've tried settings colorPrimaryDark, statusBarColor and other things in Android styles.xml. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks

Comment: Hi @season, thanks again for help. I've faced another problem, maybe you know how to fix it. When NormalTheme or SplashScreenDrawable is applied - status bar has some overlay - https://prnt.sc/tnt6sb It becomes normal as soon as Dart code initialized

Comment: so you are creating a theme for splash now for  the rest part copy the same "Statusbarcolor into other apptheme "

Comment: AppCompat requires `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` in the dependencies section of build.gradle. However as mentioned this only works for the launch screen. As soon as the Flutter process starts, the NormalTheme will come into effect and the status bar will change to a dark transparent color. For some reason io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme seems to override or ignore most of the styles entirely, including statusBarColor, something which this solution does not address.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Macklin. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @parkgrrr After a bit of a rabbit hole, I found it was a deeper issue, one that wasn't exactly solvable :(. You might want to check the following GitHub issue out (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64001) though it might not be entirely applicable today.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, work for me: I use parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" and all works.

Comment: It works, but it also changes the color of navigation bar. Do you know how to fix this?