# How to hide status bar and make content appear behind on every device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-statusbar

### Goal

I'm trying to hide status bar and make content appear behind it.

### What I have tried

On the phone I'm currently developing (Samsung Galaxy S9+), I managed to make it work with this function

```java
    public static void removeAndroidNavBar(View view){
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE       
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN              
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE           
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY        
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION  
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;        
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

which is called on the `OnCreate()` method after `SetContentView()` like this

```java
removeAndroidNavBar(getWindow().getDecorView());
```

### Problem

HOWEVER, I run the code on a OnePlus Nord 2 which is on OxygenOs, and this doesn't work. **The status bar is not displayed (there is a black space instead), but I can't figure out how to make it disappear completely, and make content appear behind it.**

### The doc

As the documentation says [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#behind),

> On Android 4.1 and higher, you can set your application's content to appear behind the status bar, so that the content doesn't resize as the status bar hides and shows. To do this, use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN. You may also need to use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE to help your app maintain a stable layout.

which is what I'm doing, and I'm encountering the problem only on the One Plus Nord 2 device

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071089/9719869

Comment: does not make any difference

Answer (score 2):

If you wants to achieve some thing like this [image]

try like this:-

```
fun Activity.makeStatusBarTransparent() {

            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    window.apply {
                        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
                        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
                        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
                        //                    addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if(hasImmersive(context)){
                                decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or
                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            }else {
//                                decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
//                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
//                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
//                                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR

                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                                    var window = getWindow();
                                    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                                    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

//                                    window.setStatusBarColor(context.getResources().getColor(color));
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        var decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
                                        decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
                                    }
                                }
                               /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                    val controller = getWindow().insetsController
                                    controller?.systemBarsBehavior = BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                                    controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
                                }*/
                            }
                        } else {
                            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        }
                        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                    }
                }
                Log.d("Has onscreen Navigation"," "+hasImmersive(context))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }

        }
```